# text message displays when you click on a button

Tags: javascript

I have code that creates a form and when you click on submit it should output the text on the screen. However my code doesn't display the message on the screen, although it quickly shows the text and then hide it.

```
<div id="form-wrap">
<form>
    <fieldset>
    <h4>Contact Form:</h4>
        <label class="labelone" for="name">Name: </label>           
        <input name="name"/>
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <input name="email" />
        <label for="comments">Comments: </label>
        <textarea name="comments"></textarea>
  </fieldset>
<fieldset>
<input class= "btn" type="submit" value="Send Email" onclick="myFunction()"/>
<input class="btn" type="reset" value="Reset Form"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
<p id="jomin">This is a message</p>
</div>
```

STYLE

```
<style type="text/css">
#jomin {    visibility:hidden;
}
</style>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()   {
document.getElementById("jomin").style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not seeing the change because the form is being submitting and the page is reloading.

Change:

```
<input class= "btn" type="submit" value="Send Email" onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

to

```
<input class= "btn" type="submit" value="Send Email" onclick="return myFunction()"/>
```

And also change

```
function myFunction()   {
    document.getElementById("jomin").style.visibility="visible";
}
```

to

```
function myFunction()   {
    document.getElementById("jomin").style.visibility="visible";
    return false;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VA4Nr/)**